# SQL query search exactly number

Tags: sql, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

table product, colunm record_no contains 11,112,3412,116,234,678

```
select distinct(record_no)
from product.
```

When i search a value 11 in the form, it returns 11,112,116 instead of only 11.
How do i make it returns value 11 only? Thanks in advance

Comment: Your query has no search criteria so it is unclear what you are doing.

Comment: `Select * from product where record_no = search_number` ... may be it can help you :)

Answer (score 2):

Looks like an **interactive report**, not a form. Is it? If so, and if you used the "search" field, then - what it does - is to search rows for occurrence of the search term in all rows. Something like

```
select * 
from product
where record_no like '%11%'
```

and yes - it returns all those values (11, 112, 116).

If you want to find *exactly* `11`, then go to "Actions" button and set a **Filter** where

- record_no
- is equal to
- 11

Answer (score 0):

SELECT DISTINCT(record_no)
FROM product
WHERE one_of_your_fields = 11

?